# PHP redirect with header

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not expert in PHP, and I'm trying to create public chatroom for my simple website.

I'm using SQL database to store messages.The file named `chat_index.php` getting all messages from database and show it to users. Also it has a simple form to send message with PHP GET method. The following is code for my form.

```
<form method="get" action="sendmessage.php">
   <input name="msg" placeholder="Message" data-theme="a" type="text">
   <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Send</button>
</form>
```

With above code I'm sending data to `sendmessage.php` file. In this file adding message to database and user redirect to `chat_index.php` with this code.

```
header("Location: chat_index.php");
exit();
```

After redirect page loading correctly on browser window. But URL end like this

> ...../sendmessage.php?msg=test_message

So if I reload the page message sending again and url getting correct like this

> ...../chat_index.php

How can I resolve this problem?

**UPDATED**

- I tried with `POST` method. but not solved. browser showing content in `chat_index.php` and url ending with `../sendmessage.php`

Comment: you are using `get` method to submit your form. change it to `post`

Comment: I tried with `POST` method. but not solved. browser showing content in `chat_index.php` and url ending with `../sendmessage.php`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are recieveing the url variables is because you are using [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). use [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) instead and the variables will be gone.

example:

```
<form method="POST" action="sendmessage.php">
```

Comment: I tried with `POST` method. but not solved. browser showing content in `chat_index.php` and url ending with `../sendmessage.php`

Comment: Please show more code so i can have a look. Im not quite sure what you mean with "browser showing content in chat_index.php"?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send data to the query string use `POST` instead of `GET`.

```
<form method="POST" action="sendmessage.php">
```

Comment: I tried with `POST` method. but not solved. browser showing content in `chat_index.php` and url ending with `../sendmessage.php`

Answer (score 0):

This should clearly be a POST form. Any form saving or changing anything on the server should be. Otherwise (using get) people could add messages by just following a link, which is not intended. The redirect after save is OK and good practice. Note that such redirects only work before any output is produced.

Cannot say much more by what you have posted. You should also check if your saving and redirect code is triggered correctly when message is posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening, the form is being submitted from chat_index.php, so the action ends up being  `chat_index.php/sendmessage.php`.
To solve this change the method to post as directed and change your action to `/sendmessage.php`
your form should look look like this

```
<form method="POST" action="/sendmessage.php">
   ....
</form
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If this is to be a simple forum site, then it would be much less complicated to not redirect at all.  Just set your action attribute to "", and when someone submits the form, it will post the data back to the page.  So do something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input name="msg" placeholder="Message" data-theme="a" type="text">
    <input name="function" type="hidden" value="post_message">
    <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Send</button>
</form>
```

Then put the php code that was in sendmessage.php into chat_index.php above the starting DOCTYPE and html tags, and delete sendmessage.php.  Or alternatively, use include('sendmessage.php') in the same spot.  Then when the page loads, check if $_POST['function'] == 'post_message', and if this condition is true, then execute the stuff you had in sendmessage.php.  That will be much more compact, and the user will be redirected once instead of twice.  Also, I don't know your file structure, but you might want to rename chat_index.php to just index.php to make it intuitive and so that people can't see inside your directory.